# Suspending worker-thread and wait for user interaction on main-thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a main UI thread that starts a SQL batch on a working thread.

The batch may generate some errors (blocking) or warnings (non-blocking).

In the first case, I finally rollback the transaction and exit thread.

In the second case, I want the user to review warning messages in the middle of the SQL batch:

1. some data are processed
2. some warnings are generated
3. user reviews these messages
4. user decides to continue or stop the batch
5. batch resumes or stops

I could possibly make a `ShowDialog()` directly from the working thread, but I don't like this solution, since this is not an UI thread.

My idea was to inform the main UI thread about the situation (*"Warnings have been generated"*) and sleep the working thread for a fixed amount of time (say 500ms). A tristate (`bool?`) is checked every time the thread wakes up, if it has not a value, thread is slept again.

When the user reviewed warnings and possibly decides to continue, the boolean is set and the next time the working thread will wake up, it will know if continue or safely abort (rollback) the batch.

Is this a so bad design-pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the "wakeup" mechanism the concept is not bad.

Instead of a `bool?` and periodically waking up the worker on its own it would be better to use a `bool` and a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). The worker notifies the UI and waits on the event (immediately blocking). The UI interacts with the user, sets the `bool` appropriately and signals the event (releasing the worker, which inspects the `bool` value and acts accordingly).

Of course the above can be implemented in a variety of manners, and the implementation leaves quite a bit of room for engineering. On one end of the scale you could have tightly coupled code with a raw flag and event, while on the other you could have an abstract "feedback service" that the worker queries.

This would enable you to swap one implementation of the feedback service for another, allowing among others:

1. Presenting a "do this for all warnings" option; if it's selected, the feedback service stops showing UI for the requests and instead answers them internally.
2. Executing an operation in "silent mode": the feedback service is configured to answer requests without showing UI (e.g. always saying "continue").

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. One more question: why would I have to use MRE rather than ARE? I have only one working-thread so the auto-reset after working-thread release would be a great feature, in my opinion...

Comment: @Teejay: Ideally the worker would block inside the "request feedback" method, so it won't know about the type of event used. The feedback service could very well use an ARE, I simply went for max flexibility by default: a new MRE is created for and discarded after each request. It's practically just as convenient as reusing a single ARE and while it may be more "wasteful" we should be wary of going for premature optimization.

Comment: My comment was not in the idea of premature-optimizing the code by reusing the single ARE. Simply, ARE seems to be more convenient for my specific case, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Teejay: I take it you mean "convenient" as in "needs less code". It would depend on how you implemented, in general yes it would need less code. Purely imagining about it though I think the amount of savings would decrease as the quality of the implementation increases.

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would use Events to do this. Like this:

1. Create an AutoResetEvent as the class member variable
2. When use interaction is required, reset the event first
3. Inform main UI thread
4. Wait on the event

In Main Thread:

1. Show the warning/error.
2. Store what is user's choice.
3. Set the event.

Now, the worker thread will wakes up and gets the main thread's result (what user selected) and proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `bool?`, why not go with some locking mechanism? `ManualResetEvent` for example could block the thread until user decides. Than his decision could set this event, causing thread to continue doing work. The way it should continue working should be passed in another variable, to make clear distinction between mechanism for blocking and information on how to continue exectution.